# PostgreSQL - How to define a trigger function to update the column with (the maximum value of the column + 1) of existing records

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-trigger

In the PostgreSQL database, the `item` table is defined

```
CREATE TABLE item
(
  "objectId" text NOT NULL,
  "createdAt" timestamp with time zone,
  "updatedAt" timestamp with time zone,
  _rperm text[],
  _wperm text[],
  item_name text,
  item_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT "ITEM_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("objectId")
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE item
  OWNER TO gc;
```

I would like to create a trigger on this table. When a new record is being inserted (not updated), the `item_id` column should have the maximum value of all existing `item_id` values plus 1. This is mimicing the auto-incrementing behaviour on item_id.

Comment: if two transactions insert rows at the same time, there may be duplicate `item_id` with this approach. is that acceptable?

Comment: Do **not** do that. A `serial` (or identity) using a sequence is the **only** sane, performant and scalable solution to create unique numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you do *not* search the table for the maximal value, since that makes you vulnerable to race conditions.

Rather, you should create a second one-element table that holds the current maximum.

Then you can get the next value in a way that is safe from race conditions:

```
UPDATE maxtab SET id = id + 1 RETURNING id;
```